# Query regarding the probabilities obtained from Logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am implementing a classification task which is a 985 class classification problem.
I have trained my model and predicted the class of X_test data.

I am using logistic regression. When I am doing clf.predict(X_test[0]) then I am getting the correct class.
But when I am seeing the probabilities, clf.predict_proba(X_test[0]), then the correct class does not have the highest probability. In fact, another class has a maximum probability. I don't understand why this is happening. I have checked for another input, the same is happening for other inputs also.

Comment: Please *show*, don't tell. No one can answer this with the amount of information (not) given.

Answer (score -1):

This is really hard to troubleshoot without an example to replicate. However, I suspect that there may be an indexing problem. Try restarting the notebook kernel if you're using a notebook, and check for indexing problems.

Also, if you could post more details or examples of this happening, it would help.